# Why does my empty object literal log as false?

Tags: javascript

I don't quite understand why the `if` statement evaluates `true` but the `console.log` comparison does not.

I double checked the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) and they say `{}` is a truthy value. So why does my `console.log` statement disagree?

I did try, as a last ditch, using `==` instead of `===`.

```js
var test = {};
    
console.log(test);          
console.log(test === true); 
console.log({} === true);   
    
if ({}) {
    console.log('What the ?');
}
```

Comment: Simply because `x == true` is not a way of testing whether or not `x` is truthy. `Boolean(x) == true` is, `!!{} == true`.

Comment: *"Truthy"* does not mean *"is equal to true"*, it means *"is equal to true **when evaluated as a boolean***. Try converting it to a bool first: `console.log(!!{} === true);`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons - `===` checks 'is this the same as', whereas `==` checks 'can this be coerced to be the same as. An if statement can be considereed to be using the latter. so `{}` is not the same as `true`, but it is 'truth-y', that is, it can be coerced to true

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`===` is not the way to check whether a value is truthy in the way you are checking. 
For example, all the following are truthy. But if you try to do `===` with `true` they will result in `false` other than the truthy value `true`

```
if (true)
if ({})
if ([])
if (42)
if ("foo")
if (new Date())
if (-42)
if (3.14)
if (-3.14)
if (Infinity)
if (-Infinity)
```

```js
console.log(true === true);
console.log({} === true);
console.log([] === true);
console.log(42 === true);
console.log("foo" === true);
console.log((new Date()) === true);
console.log(-42 === true);
console.log(3.14 === true);
console.log(-3.14 === true);
console.log(Infinity === true);
console.log(-Infinity === true);
```

You can check truthy by using `!!value`. For example

```js
var test = {};
console.log(!!test === true);
```

Similarly we can check for all the truthy above as following:

```js
console.log(!!true === true);
console.log(!!{} === true);
console.log(!![] === true);
console.log(!!42 === true);
console.log(!!"foo" === true);
console.log(!!(new Date()) === true);
console.log(!!-42 === true);
console.log(!!3.14 === true);
console.log(!!-3.14 === true);
console.log(!!Infinity === true);
console.log(!!-Infinity === true);
```

Comment: Thoughts on use of !! as far as readability/properness of it? I'm in school right now for JS, so still learning. Thank you

Comment: If you want it more readable, you can always use `Boolean(val)` instead of `!!val` to convert to boolean

Comment: @MattWeber `!!x` is commonly used to convert a value to a boolean. It is readable because it is a widely recognized. If you find `Boolean(x)` more readable, use that; both are equally correct.

Answer (score 0):

`{}` is truthy in JavaScript, that's why the if block is executed.

However, it is not strictly `true` so the triple equal comparison gives you false.

More info:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness

Answer (score 0):

`===` is [strict equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators). It first checks whether the types of its operands are the same, then whether they have the same value.

In `{} === true`, the left side has type `object` while the right side has type `boolean`, so it evaluates to `false`.

Many values are not equal to `true` but are still truthy. Similarly, there are values that are falsy but not equal to `false`.

Comment: Both these answers focus on the `===` even though the OP mentions that he observed the same thing with `==`.

Comment: @Paulpro That's because OP's question focuses on `===`. My last paragraph is a general statement about equality that applies to both `===` and `==`.

Comment: OP's question doesn't focus on `===`. He wants to know why `{} == true` is `false`, even though `{}` is truthy.

Comment: @Paulpro That's not what the question says: "*So why does my console.log statement disagree?*" And the `console.log` statements all use `===`.